# regex: Numbers and spaces (10 or 14 numbers)

Tags: regex

How I can write a regex which accepts 10 or 14 digits separated by a single space in groups of 1,2 or 3 digits?

examples: 
`123 45 6 789 1 is valid`
`1234 567 8 9 1 is not valid` (group of 4 digits)
`123 45 6 789 109 123 8374 is not valid` (not 10 or 14 digits)

**EDIT**
This is what I have tried so far

```
[0-9 ]{10,14}+
```

But it validates also 11,12,13 numbers, and doesn't check for group of numbers

Comment: Did you try any [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)?

Comment: I don't think you should try to accomplish this via regex alone.

Comment: I don't understand the obsession with getting everything done in a single regex. This is trivial if you break it down into a few different matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with lookahead assertion:

```
^(?=(?:\d ?){10}(?:(?:\d ?){4})?$)\d{1,3}(?: \d{1,3})+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1dwsBS/1)

- Here `(?=...)` is lookahead assertion that enforces presence of 10 or 14 digits in input.
- `\d{1,3}(?: \d{1,3})+` matches input with 1 to 3 digits separated by space with no space allowed at start or end.

Comment: Great combination of lookahead with a "regular" pattern! This effectively makes it possible to enforce two regexes in one. +1

Answer (score 0):

aggtr,

You can match your use case with the following:

```
^(?:\d\s?){10}$|^(?:\d\s?){14}$
```

^ means the beginning of the string and $ means the end of the string.
(?:...) means a non-capturing group. Thus, the part before the | means a string that starts and has a non-capturing group of a decimal followed by an optional space that has exactly 10 items followed by the end of the string. By putting the | you allow for either 10 or 14 of your pattern.

**Edit** I missed the part of your requirement to have the digits grouped by 1, 2, or 3 digits.